# Freeing memory in C with basic trim example

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to implement a `trim` function in C, and in doing so I'm using two sub-functions, `ltrim` and `rtrim`. I was wondering if I'm "leaking" memory somehow by calling `malloc` so much. If so, where should I be `free`ing the memory or altering how the `malloc` is called?

Ltrim:

```
char * rtrim(char * string) {
    
    size_t slen = strlen(string);
    char * modified_string = malloc(slen + 1);
    strcpy(modified_string, string);
    
    for (int i=slen-1; i>0 ;i--) {
        if (string[i] == ' ' || string[i] == '\t')
            modified_string[i] = '\0';
        else
            break;
    }
    
    return modified_string;
}
```

Rtrim:

```
char * ltrim(char * string) {
    
    char c;
    int start_index = -1;
    
    char * modified_string = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    
    for (int i=0; (c=string[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if ((c == ' ' || c == '\t') && (start_index == -1)) {   
            ;       
        } else {
            if (start_index == -1) start_index = i;
            modified_string[i - start_index] = c;
        }
    }
    return modified_string;
}
```

Trim:

```
char * trim(char * string) {
    char * string1 = ltrim(string);
    char * string2 = rtrim(string1);
    return string2;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char * new_str = "   howlin   ";
    printf("Original: \"%s\" | RTrimmed: \"%s\"\n", new_str, rtrim(new_str));
    printf("Original: \"%s\" | LTrimmed: \"%s\"\n", new_str, ltrim(new_str));
    printf("Original: \"%s\" | Trimmed: \"%s\"\n", new_str, trim(new_str));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " if I'm "leaking" memory" --> Yes, so far.  Code relies on the caller's of `ltim(), rtrim()` to `free()`.  Why not `free(string1)`?

Comment: @chux thanks for this suggestion. Could you show an example please of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions aren't technically leaking memory, but they're making it really easy for the calling code to leak memory.  Case in point: your sample `main` function leaked the buffers returned by the three calls to `ltrim`/`rtrim`, and your `trim` function leaked `string1`.

Instead, consider how these can be simplified.  `ltrim` doesn't need to allocate memory at all.  It can simply return a pointer to the first non-space character in the input string.  `rtrim` isn't so easy, though.

One way to avoid the memory problems entirely is to have the functions modify the input string.  Your output is never longer than the input, so you'll always have enough buffer available.  `rtrim` would simply replace the first whitespace character at the end of the string with `'\0'`, and `ltrim` would `memmove()` using a pointer to the first non-whitespace character.  Modifying the strings in place means that the caller knows that they're responsible for making copies, allocating buffers, etc. and makes it harder to accidentally leak memory.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for the suggestions here. Is returning the original data/point in memory rather than returning a copy usually the way how C functions work? Or does it really just depend?

Comment: @TagC198 There's not a standard way to do it.  Functions do whatever makes the most sense in that particular context.  Whichever way you decide to go, make sure the function's documentation clearly indicates what's going on.  There's nothing worst than a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 0):

> If so, where should I be freeing the memory or altering how the malloc is called?

Consider re-architecting  your helper functions `ltrim()`, `rtrim()` without `malloc()` and let the calling code handle allocations.

```
// Return beginning of trimmed string.
const char *ltrim(const char * string) {
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *string) {
    string++;
  }
  return string;
}

// Return end of "trimmed" string.
const char *rtrim(const char * string) {
  // find first non-space
  const char *non_space = string;
  while (isspace((unsigned char) **non_space) {
    *non_space++;
  }
  if (*non_space) {
    // Quickly go to the null character.
    string = non_space + strlen(*non_space);
    // While the character to the "left" is a space, backup.
    // Here we know there is a non-white-space somewhere to the left,
    // so loop will end with only a `isspace()` test.
    while (isspace((unsigned char) string[-1]) {
      string--;
    }
  }
  return string;
}
```

Now armed with these helper functions ....

```
char * trim_alloc(const char * string) {
  string = ltrim(string);
  const char *end = rtrim(string);
  size_t length = end - string;
  char *copy = malloc(length + 1);
  if (copy) {
    memcpy(copy, string, length);
    copy[length] = '\0';
  }  
  return copy;
}
```

---

Was is speedy about `rtrim` is that each of its 3 loops (`while, strlen, while`) are each only testing for one condition and not 2 like "isspace && not null_character".  This approach works best with sizable strings with a small amount of right trimming.

Comment: this is great. Unfortunately my reputation is too low to upvote your answer, but once I hit that threshold I'll come back and do so. Thanks for the answer!